# the refresh the page i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hello I have an application in react and it is working perfectly. All routes, page loads. Everything perfect. However, when entering the FarmProperty page and trying to reload it (F5) the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tenant_account' of undefined` occurs.

**FarmProperty.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/farmProperty';

class FarmProperty extends Component {

    state = {
        page: 0,
        limit: 15,
        msg: "",
        erro: "",
        success: "",
        loading: false,
        openModal: false,
        id_delete: "",
        tenant_account_id_delete: "",
        apiData: false
    }

    
     componentDidMount() {
        this.getFarmProperties();
    }

     componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (!this.props.user && nextProps.user) this.getFarmProperties();
        this.receiveApiData();
    }


     getFarmProperties() {
        const { page, limit } = this.state;
        const { farm_properties, user } = this.props;
        //console.log(user);
        
        this.props.getFarmProperties(user.tenant_account.id, page, limit);
        
        if (this.props.location.state) {
            this.setState({ msg: this.props.location.state.msg });
            this.props.location.state.msg = "";
        }
        if (farm_properties === "undefined") return null;
    }

     receiveApiData() {
        if (typeof this.props.farm_properties !== "undefined" && this.props.farm_properties !== null
            && !this.state.apiData && this.props.farm_properties.data.currentPageNumber === this.state.page) {
            this.setState({ apiData: true });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>

            </>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    farm_properties: state.farmProperty.farm_properties,
    user: state.auth.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(FarmProperty);
```

I believe the problem lies in the function
`this.props.getFarmProperties (user.tenant_account.id, page, limit);`

when I'm passing the `user.tenant_account.id` parameter. This parameter is the user who is logged in to the application and I need to get this information, but if there is any other way to get this information, I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: How are you persisting the `user` in your store across page refreshes? If you are not you will need to do that in some way with something like `redux-persist` so your store is not empty when reloading. You may also want to check for the existence of `user` and redirect to the login page if one doesn't exist.